# Terminal error MacOS: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1634:1: note:

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, compiler-errors, xcode-debugger

An error is generated when I try to run my C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> //standard c++ library of time.h 
using namespace std; 

class DateCplusplus{
private: 
    int _day, _month, _year; //define variable 
public: 
    void readValues(){
        cout<<"Enter the day value: "; 
        cin>>_day; 
        cout<<"\nEnter the month value: "; 
        cin>>_month; 
        cout>>_year; 
        _year = _year - 1900; 
    }

    int verifyValues(){
        if(_day>=1 && _day <=31 && _month>=1 && _month<= 12){
            return 1; 
        }
        return 0; 
    }

    int compareValues(){
        time_t now = time(0); 
        tm *ltm = localtime(&now); 
        if((_year == ltm -> tm_year) && (_month ==1 +ltm -> tm_mon) && (_day == ltm -> tm_mday)){
            return 1; 
        }
        return 0; 
    }

    int main(){
        DateCplusplus date; 
        date.readValues(); 
        cout<<"\nVerification of day and months values: "<<date.verifyValues()<<"\n"; 
        cout<<"\nComparision of the day, the month and the year with the System current Date: "<<date.compareValues(); 
        return 0; 
    }
};
```

The error showing in the terminal is: 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1634:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream' against 'basic_ostream'
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, bitset<_Size>& __x)

Can you help me find my mistake ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main function cannot be contained any classes so i extracted your main function from class DateCplusplus and you have syntax error that cou>>_year, it has to be cout<<_year.And you have to define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS top of the code if you want to run.Because localtime is unsafe function.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS


#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 

using namespace std;

class DateCplusplus {
private:
    int _day, _month, _year; //define variable 
public:
    void readValues() {
        cout << "Enter the day value: ";
        cin >> _day;
        cout << "\nEnter the month value: ";
        cin >> _month;
        cout << _year;
        _year = _year - 1900;
    }

    int verifyValues() {
        if (_day >= 1 && _day <= 31 && _month >= 1 && _month <= 12) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int compareValues() {
        time_t now = time(0);
        tm* ltm = localtime(&now);
        if ((_year == ltm->tm_year) && (_month == 1 + ltm->tm_mon) && (_day == ltm->tm_mday)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};



    int main() {
        DateCplusplus date;
        date.readValues();
        cout << "\nVerification of day and months values: " << date.verifyValues() << "\n";
        cout << "\nComparision of the day, the month and the year with the System current Date: " << date.compareValues();
        return 0;
    }
```